# Keep on clearing text present in edit text when I hold the button

Tags: android, button, textview

I have a text view in which the user can enter data at run time using the custom buttons that I have created.
My delete button is able to delete one character at a time but if i hold the button then it stops.
I want the text field to get cleared when i hold the button.
Is there any solution to this....??
Please help me out.
This is my xml,

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/btnClear"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               >

                 <ImageView
                     android:id="@+id/imgClear"
                     android:layout_width="20dp"
                     android:layout_height="20dp"
                     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                     android:layout_centerVertical="true"

                     android:src="@drawable/img_clear" />

                </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my code,

```
 imgClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String getNumber;

                    if(isFirstNum){

                        getNumber = txtFirstNumber.getText().toString();

                        if(getNumber.length() > 0)
                        txtFirstNumber.setText(getNumber.substring(0, getNumber.length()-1));



                    } else if(!isFirstNum){

                        getNumber = txtSecondNumber.getText().toString();

                        if(getNumber.length() > 0)
                            txtSecondNumber.setText(getNumber.substring(0, getNumber.length()-1));

                    }



                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `onLongClickListener` to check if the delete button is pressed for a long time

```
imgClear.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v)
    {
        txtFirstNumber.setText("");
        return true;
    }
});
```

This will set your `txtFirstNumber` to blank but the `onClickListener` will not be called.

Comment: this clears the edit text on button hold but now i cannot delete a character one by one.
I want both of these functionality to work simultaneously.

Comment: Did you debug and check whether your `OnClickListener` is being called? Because it is working for me.

Comment: it worked.....
but due to setText("") the text in the field wipes out immediately..
i want that when i hold the the button the fields get cleared like in whats app any other text space in our smartphones....
i want to delete character by character when i hold the button and character by character when i tap the button...

Comment: Use a `for` loop and do what you do on your `onClickListener`

Comment: Sorry i don't have an example.

Comment: What i want is that when i tap the button the field gets cleared character by character and when i hold the button the also it gets cleared character by character like it is whats app.. hope you understand now....

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But as per my understanding you want to clear the text of the text view then in your button click listener just set the text for textview to empty.
eg:

```
public void onClick(View v){  
          textview.setText("");  
    }
```

Comment: this will set an empty text view when i click the button. What i want is that when i tap the button the field gets cleared character by character and when i hold the button the also it gets cleared character by character like it is whats app..
hope you understand now....